# node-dbox issue with path.join Error on trying to use metadata

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox-api, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to use the node-dbox to list my content in Dropbox. I did the connection with OAuth and it does pass but when I try to do the client.metadata function it shows a path.join Error . Here is the code ...

app/index.js :

```
// MODULE REQUIERMENTS
var dbox=require('dbox'),
    http= require('http'),
    fs=require('fs'),
    path= require('path'),
    express=require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    multipart=require('connect-multiparty');


//PATH JSON AUTH FILE 
var auth_path=path.join(__dirname,'../auth.json'),
    config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(auth_path)),
    dboxapp= dbox.app(config),
    token=false,
    client = false ;

//NEW EXPRESS 
var app = new express();

// MIDDLEWARE FOR MULTIPART
var  multipartMiddleware= multipart();

//SET THE JADE VIEWS
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine','jade'); 
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

app.use(function(req,res,next) {
    if (client || token) {
        next();
    } else{
        dboxapp.requesttoken(function(status,request_token) {
            token=request_token;
            var oAuthURL = request_token.authorize_url +  '&oauth_callback=http://localhost:3000/access';
            res.redirect(oAuthURL);
        });
    };
});

app.get('/access',function (req,res) {
    dboxapp.accesstoken(token,function(status,access_token) {
        client= dboxapp.client(access_token);
        res.redirect('/album.json');
    });
});

app.get('/album',function (req,res) {
    console.log(client);
    client.metadata("/",{list:true},function (status, reply) {
        console.log(reply);
        res.render('layout',reply);
    });
});

app.get('/album.json',function (req,res) {
    client.metadata('/ ',function (status, reply) {
        res.json(reply);
    });
});

module.exports=app;
```

views/layout.jade

```
doctype html
html 
  head 
    title Cova Nosejs API Dropbox 
    link(rel="stylesheet",href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css")
  body
    ul 
      each file in contents
        li= file.path
```

The Console Error Message :

```
ropboxAPI> Express server (DropboxAPI) listening on port 3000
[Function]
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
    at path.js:360:15
    at Array.filter (native)
    at Object.exports.join (path.js:358:36)
    at Object.url (/Documents/workspace/DropboxAPI/node_modules/dbox/lib/helpers.js:127:27)
    at Object.metadata (/Documents/workspace/DropboxAPI/node_modules/dbox/lib/dbox.js:200:29)
    at Object.module.exports [as handle] (/Documents/workspace/DropboxAPI/app/index.js:59:9)
    at next_layer (/Documents/workspace/DropboxAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Documents/workspace/DropboxAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
    at /Documents/workspace/DropboxAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:213:24
    at Function.proto.process_params (/Documents/workspace/DropboxAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:12)
```

Comment: Can you share your config? (Be sure to X out any secrets.) Specifically, is there a `scope` field somewhere? According to the error, the issue is on line https://github.com/sintaxi/node-dbox/blob/master/lib/helpers.js#L127, which I guess means that `scope` is not a string...?

Comment: Is not much there just the server.js `var http = require('http'),
 repl=require('repl'),
 app = require('./app');


http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Express server (DropboxAPI) listening on port ' + 3000);
});` and the auth.json with a key of Dropbox API `{
 "app_key":"xxx",
 "app_secret":"xxxx"
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could try explicitly coercing the arguments into strings...

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname.toString(),'public')));
```

Comment: unfortunately your recommendation did not work is still sending the same error. I think it is related to the node-dbox..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that this isn't much of an answer, but sometimes it helps to start small and work up to the problem. Here's some code that works for me, using Node version 0.10.24 on OS X and dbox version 0.6.3 (current from npm):

```
var APPKEY = '<REDACTED>',
    APPSECRET = '<REDACTED>';

var dbox = require('dbox'),
    readline = require('readline');

var app = dbox.app({
    app_key: APPKEY,
    app_secret: APPSECRET
});

app.requesttoken(function (status, requestToken) {
    console.log('Go to https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=' + requestToken.oauth_token);
    rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
    rl.setPrompt('Press enter once you\'ve authorized: ');
    rl.prompt();
    rl.on('line', function (line) {
        app.accesstoken(requestToken, function (status, accessToken) {
            var client = app.client(accessToken);
            client.metadata('/', function (status, reply) {
                console.log(reply);
            });
        })
        rl.close();
    });
});
```

Could you try out this code and see if it works? If so, we can try to figure out what's different about your code. (If not, we can try to figure out what's different about your environment.)

Answer (score 0):

After checking the dependencies on the package.json the dbox was set like this  `"dbox": "*"` and it was not taking the latest version (which is the 0.6.3).

the Fix for this case was to specify the version `"dbox":"0.6.3"`